# jquery help getting my id

Tags: jquery

i have 2 simple links on my page. how do i use jQuery to get the id's or values of those links?

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('a').each(function()
{
    alert(this.id + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("your-selector-here").attr("id");
```

to get the ID, and:

```
$("your-selector-here").text();
```

to get the text enclosed in the link.

You'll need to decide how best to identify each link using a jQuery selector, and replace "your-selector-here" with your selector in the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

If your links are simple anchors you could do it this way:

To get the ID:

```
$("a").each(function() { $(this).attr("id"); });
```

To get the value or the text:

```
$("a").each(function() { $(this).text(); });
```